# Using element-react library in Gatsy.js

Tags: webpack, internationalization, gatsby

I'm trying to use the UI library, element-react, with Gatsby.js.

From the element-react docs, [doc1](https://elemefe.github.io/element-react/#/en-US/i18n) and [doc2](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element-react), I need to configure webpack.

I cannot figure out how to customise the webpack configuration in gatsby-node.js.

Below is the webpack customisation needed, from the element-react docs:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    src: 'path/to/src'
  },
  output: {
    path: 'path/to/output'
    publicPath: '/public',
    chunkFilename: '[chunkhash:12].js',
    filename: '[chunkhash:12].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      output: {
        comments: false
      }
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: ['path/to/src']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2)(\?.+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[hash:12].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```